# javascript TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'something')

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I have this data taken from an api.

```
{
  "id": "01",
  "title": "xxxx",
  "imagePath": "/courses/xxx.jpg",
  "price": {
    "early_bird": 300,
    "normal": 500
  },
  "dates": {
    "start_date": "2023-01-12",
    "end_date": "2023-02-05"
  },
  "duration": "3 weeks",
  "online": true,
  "description": "xxxx"
}
```

When I try to access `data.price.normal`, I have this error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'normal')

My code is this

```
export default function CourseSinglePage() {

    const { id } = useParams(); // Get the id parameter from the URL

    var _data = getCourse(id);
    console.log(_data)


    return (
        <Card>
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            height="200"
            image={_data.imagePath}
            alt={_data.title}
          />
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
              {_data.title}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
              {_data.description}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p" >
              Price: {_data.price.normal}| Online : {_data.online ? <CheckCircle color="success" fontSize='5'/> : <Cancel color="error" fontSize='5' />}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
              Duration:{_data.duration}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
              Dates: 
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
              Description: {_data.description}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      );
    };
```

If I delete the `_data.price.normal` and leave it empty it works fine

```
export function  getCourse(id){
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/courses/${id}`)
        .then(response => {
            setData(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }, []);
    return data;
}
```

I tried accessing it like this _data.price['normal'] and this _data['price].normal

Comment: What is getCourse? is it function, component or custom hook?

Comment: You should wrap your card inside conditional. When there is _data then only render the jsx.

Comment: Have you tried [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)? You can try and write `_data?.price?.normal`

Comment: @PeterKrebs Yes i tried, this is the output ./src/pages/cousesinglepage.js 71:21
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (71:21)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       columnNumber: 13
|     }
>   }, "Price:", _data?.price?.normal, " | Online : ", _data.online ? /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(CheckCircle, {
|     color: "success",
|     fontSize: "5",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add some verification.

some of your data must be missing the price.

the latest ecmascript specification supports optional chaining(`_data?.price?.normal`), but depending on the environment, the syntax may not be supported.

so instead you can use:

`_data.price && _data.price.normal`

and avoid trying to read data from an undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

data.price.normal this method is correct only, first you need to store the same data in a variable then fetch it will work.

Comment: can you give me an example ?